# Calculate difference between 2 date-time in soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using SoapUI free version. I have a REST response that returns date-time like this

```
<startTime>2018-02-22T17:10:00-05:00</startTime>
<endTime>2018-02-22T18:05:00-05:00</endTime>
```

How do I calculate the difference between them (in minutes) using groovy test step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Assuming string teased out of response, if not you need to extract the value to a string....
def startString = '<startTime>2018-02-22T17:10:00-05:00</startTime>';
def endString     = '<endTime>2018-02-22T18:05:00-05:00</endTime>';

// If you have the tags, ditch them.
startString = startString.replace("<startTime>", "");
startString = startString.replace("</startTime>", "");

endString = endString.replace('<endTime>', '');
endString = endString.replace('</endTime>', '');

log.info("Now just strings... ${startString} - ${endString}");


// Convert strings to dates...
def convertedStartDate = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX",startString);
def convertedEndDate = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX",endString);

log.info("Now dates...  ${convertedStartDate} - ${convertedEndDate}");


//Use time category to tease out the values of interest...
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def duration = convertedEndDate - convertedStartDate
    log.info( "Days: ${duration.days}, Hours: ${duration.hours}, Minutes: ${duration.minutes}, Seconds: ${duration.seconds}, etc.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt solution. This works exactly as needed.